# How would an immortal character amass a fortune?

Tags: immortality

As the title says how would someone who is immortal, and driven by collecting vast sums of money be able to exploit that to their own gain.

For context my main character was involved in experiments in the 1950s to produce even more powerful atomic weapons and power sources, when an incident with highly unstable handwavium caused her to become immortal, but not invincible she can still be injured, maimed etc but what would be fatal injuries to a normal human simply put her in a coma for several months while her body recovers. She no longer ages or gets sick, but the limits of this regeneration are untested and she has no intention of pushing them. Many labs around the world have attempted to reproduce this incident unsuccessfully, only leading only to the agonising deaths of the test subjects. So selling the ability to others is off the table. I've not yet decided whether she is open or reserved about this ability so suggestions on either side.

Comment: Welcome to the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange! A very interesting question with potential. Please keep in mind that character-based questions are not permitted on this site. Since the question would otherwise bee too broad, please edit your question to try and make it more specific. Give me an @ after you've edited.

Comment: If you should be more interested in exploring the character, [the Writing Stack Exchange](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) would be just the place for you!

Comment: @A Lambent Eye, thanks for the advice I think it would be better suited there in hindsight, is it possible to transport across or should I repost there?

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't an on-topic question on Writing. As mentioned in https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7341/29, Writing SE is about *techniques*. If you had an idea and were struggling with how to get it across to your readers, then Writing would probably be the place to go ask about *that*; but if all you have is a goal for a character, and want to come up with ideas for how the character might achieve that goal, that's decidedly a "what to write" question which is specifically off topic there. Thinking of something while writing does not make it a Writing question.

Comment: The same way we (probably - haven't actually tested it yet) non-immortals do.  Find some line of work at which you can make more than a survival-level income.  (Starting in the 1950s, electronics or computers look good.)  Invest the excess in some good mutual funds.  50 years laters, you've got a modest fortune, even if you miss out on the really good startups :-)

Comment: You may find some inspiration at my question here: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/121353/fastest-way-for-an-invincible-young-immortal-to-make-1-million-usd

Comment: @Nosajimiki Not arguing against you, but not really sure why you pinged me with that. I assume you're not using that to argue that this should be on topic on *Writing* (which is what my comment was all about), and with the current reopen vote, this should be in the reopen review queue here on Worldbuilding. The question was put on hold as part of the process of migrating it to Writing, which was requested by OP and where it was closed as off topic.

Comment: Sorry, I read your statement wrong

Comment: The character might not know that they won't age until they begin to seem ageless.  So at first they will plan for a normal life.  They might retire with enough money for a normal length retirement and run out of money and have to acquire more.  But if they are really immortal and manage investments that grow even slightly faster than inflation they will become super rich after centuries or millennia.  And by super rich I mean multi billionaires, trillionaires, quadrillionaires, etc.   If one's investment doubles every X years, after 10X years it will be 1,024 times as large continued

Comment: continued and after 20X years it will be 1,048,576, times as large, after 30X years it will be 1,073,741,824 times as large, and so on.  If one pessimistically assumes that the increase in value over inflation will be so slight that X will equal 100 years, it will still take "only" 3,000 years for the immortal to increase the value of an initial investment by over one billion times.

Comment: This question has been the subject of considerable discussion on Meta.  There's some simple reality: questions about individual characters have always been off-topic (even if they occasionally get past us) because the actions of an individual are always storybuilding.  Even if we let that slide, the question is [primarily opinion-based](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6437/40609).  I'm afraid the truth is there is no stack where authors can simply fish for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Given that inflation works against you just working at minimum wage and saving won't work. You could of course wait until you are 200 years old and then go on tours and be famous and sell books like 'how to live forever'. This will not give you billions, but definitely a couple million. Now you just work with those. Invest, invest, invest. As soon as you have 1-5 million just invest them, you will already be famous so opening a restaurant chain for example would still have your name behind it, making them popular by default without having to struggle like many entrepreneurs.

Comment: 1) Actually, working in a reasonably remunerative field (such as software), avoiding extravagance, & investing sensibly can give you a modest fortune in 30 years or so.  2) Trump is about the worst possible example here.  He has lied about his wealth since young adulthood; the $1 million loan is just one of those lies.  In fact, he was given access to & then inherited his father's real estate empire, around $400 million in today's dollars.  He has probably not increased his net worth much if at all, though of course we can't be sure because he's afraid to release his tax returns.

Comment: Okay, ignoring the bad example of trump, it would still work probably, would it not?

Comment: High risk investments with little probability to explosively grow like a restaurant could be worse as an immortal since it will eventually fail taking all your money with it.  Instead, low risk diversified investments that return just a bit over inflation year after year will be better for someone who will have more opportunities in their life to lose everything they have.

Comment: @Nosajimiki I mean, as soon as you are famous you do have a lot of money, and an unlimited source of such. Food and rent is an expense that hinders many people today from accumulating a lot of money. But I agree, there might be other approaches like spending your life studying and have a good job, while the famous route is easier I think.

Comment: Fame will be helpful for a few years, and can kickstart a fortune, but public interest would soon wain.  20 years after people learn you are immortal, people won't still care much, and if you do a lot of investment into your own fame, you create a market bubble for yourself that will eventually pop, and lead to you losing your wealth as quickly as you made it if you're not careful.  Fame does still make a difference, sure, but plenty of restaurants start up with good hooks that loose interest quickly

Comment: @Nosajimiki, well, you have 20 years to switch from 'public figure' to 'brand name'. If, in those 20 years, your restaurants are know for their quality and so on, they will still bring profit a decade on. And with the wealth you acuumulated from being famous you can just buy, idk, a shitton of land and lease it to farmers before population becomes so high, you lease it to building companies for a fortune and have a small city. Or you build it yourself. Yes, minimum wage would get you there too, but at some point you will have to invest. If the amount of earned money doesn't rise, it wont help.